# Change selected row color in NatTable

Tags: java, nattable

How do I change the default row selection color? I do not see where to access this in the code snippet below:

```
    SelectionLayer selectionLayer = glazedListsGridLayer.getBodyLayerStack()
       .getSelectionLayer();

    selectionLayer.setSelectionModel(new RowSelectionModel<T>(selectionLayer,
            glazedListsGridLayer.getBodyDataProvider(), myRowIdAccessor));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a style for the DisplayMode.SELECT. This can be done with a custom style configuration, a theme configuration or CSS if you are in an Eclipse 4 application.

To get a basic understanding of the styling concepts have a look here: https://eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=styling

To see how the default selection style configuration is configured check the DefaultSelectionStyleConfiguration

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've seen that link but I don't know how to define a 'selected' style attribute and I don't know how to hook a style into the RowSelectionModel. Is there a code snippet for that?

Comment: The selection model has nothing to do with the styling. Styles are applied via ConfigRegistry. Are you aware of the configuration design in NatTable? Otherwise check http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#architecture_configuration and the snippet is basically in the DefaultSelectionStyleConfiguration

Comment: I was able to get it working by doing   `nattable.addConfiguration(new DefaultSelectionStyleConfiguration(){
   {
    selectionBgColor = GUIHelper.COLOR_BLUE; 
   }
  });`